# I'd like to know if there would be best approach using laravel in making join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

and now I am making a join query in three tables with this basic sql query

```
select `modules`.`id`, `sub_modules`.`id` AS `sub_module_id`, `sub_modules`.`name`
from `module_groups`
inner join `positions` on `positions`.`id` = `module_groups`.`position_id`
inner join `modules` on `modules`.`id` = `module_groups`.`module_id`
inner join `sub_modules` on `sub_modules`.`module_id` = `modules`.`id`
where `positions`.`id` = 1
```

I'd like to know if there is best of it using laravel eloquent

so far I've tried this

```
$module = new ModuleGroup();
$name   = $module
  ->select('modules.id as modules_id', 'sub_modules.id as sub_modules_id', 'sub_modules.name as sub_module_name')
  ->join('positions', 'positions.id','=','module_groups.position_id')
  ->join('modules', 'modules.id','=','module_groups.module_id')
  ->join('sub_modules', 'sub_modules.module_id','=','modules.id')
  ->where('positions.id', '=', 1)
  ->get();
```

It works, but I'd like to know if there would be best approach using laravel.

Can you give me?

Comment: Laravel best approach is using Laravel Relationship way. Its easier and much faster. Look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I'm not a Laravel expert, but your current attempts seems to fully represent the original series of joins.  Maybe the bigger question is do you have indices setup in your tables to make that join fast.

Comment: @Qazi relationships are convenient and idiomatic to Laravel but certainly not faster - loading each relationship requires it's own query. In this particular case 4 queries have to be made to fetch necessary groups with relations. A single and proper raw query would be more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off sticking with query builder than going with eloquent based on your query. Also you have a model for just `module_groups` and performing raw joins, which isn't eloquent.

You can use query builder like shown below for your sql query.

```
$result = \DB::table('module_groups')
    ->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'module_groups.position_id')
    ->join('modules', 'modules.id','=', 'module_groups.module_id')
    ->join('sub_modules', 'sub_modules.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')
    ->where('positions.id', 1)
    ->selectRaw('modules.id as modules_id, sub_modules.id as sub_modules_id, sub_modules.name as sub_module_name')
    ->get();
```

If you really want to use only eloquent then you need to define models for all your tables and declare their relationships. Judging from the relationship in your sql query, the eloquent way would be like shown below.

```
$result = ModuleGroup::whereHas('positions', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 1);
    })
    ->with('positions', 'modules.subModules')
    ->selectRaw('modules.id as modules_id, sub_modules.id as sub_modules_id, sub_modules.name as sub_module_name')
    ->get();
```